# JENA: How to get List of base classes from ontmodel?

Tags: java, jena

I have ontology model like:

- Assertion subClassOf owl:Thing
- Chapter subClassOf owl:Thing
- Event subClassOf owl:Thing

  - DailyEvent subClassOf Event
  - HistoricEvent subClassOf Event

I want to get a list of my base classes, that is Assertion, Chapter, Event from ontmodel not list of all classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `listHierarchyRootClasses()` method on `OntModel`.

```
        Path path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        String ontologyFile = "file:" + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/src/main/resources/BaseClasses.owl";

        OntModel defaultModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        defaultModel.read(ontologyFile);

        for (ExtendedIterator<OntClass> i =  defaultModel.listHierarchyRootClasses(); i.hasNext();) {
            OntClass ontClass = i.next();
            logger.debug("Base class = " + ontClass);
        }
```